# Prototype pollution in webpack loader-utils

Tags: angular, webpack, angular12

I have created a angular12 application and pushed into GitHub repository. I have been getting a prototype pollution issue under security vulnerabilities as a critical issue under security tab.

showing a versioning issue in loader-utils with below message how can I fix this ? is it really a vulnerability issue ?

Prototype pollution vulnerability in function parseQuery in parseQuery.js in webpack loader-utils prior to version 2.0.3 via the name variable in parseQuery.js.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5vwa.png)

```
my packages.json

{
  "name": "Commercial-App",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "c8ycli server -u",
    "build": "c8ycli build",
    "deploy": "c8ycli deploy"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "11.1.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "11.1.2",
    "@angular/common": "11.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "11.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "11.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "11.1.2",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/material": "^11.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "11.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "11.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "11.1.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "11.1.2",
    "@c8y/ng1-modules": "1011.0.14",
    "@c8y/ngx-components": "1011.0.14",
    "@c8y/style": "1011.0.14",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^6.1.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "13.0.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.182",
    "angular": "1.6.9",
    "angular-ng-autocomplete": "^2.0.5",
    "angular2-multiselect-dropdown": "^5.0.4",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "fontawesome": "^5.6.3",
    "highcharts": "^9.3.3",
    "highcharts-angular": "^2.10.0",
    "html2canvas": "^1.4.1",
    "jspdf": "^2.5.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "lodash-es": "^4.17.21",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.34",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.3.8",
    "ng-template": "^1.0.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^6.2.0",
    "ngx-daterange": "^1.0.48",
    "ngx-toastr": "^13.2.1",
    "ngx-toggle-switch": "^2.0.5",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.1101.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "11.1.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "11.1.2",
    "@angular/localize": "11.1.2",
    "@c8y/cli": "1011.0.14",
    "@types/lodash-es": "^4.17.3",
    "@types/webpack": "^5.28.0",
    "typescript": "4.0.7"
  },
  "c8y": {
    "application": {
      "name": "Commercial App",
      "contextPath": "Commercial-App",
      "key": "Commercial-App-application-key",
      "brandingEntry": "./ui-assets/index.less",
      "tabsHorizontal": true,
      "upgrade": true,
      "rightDrawer": true,
      "breadcrumbs": true,
      "indexTemplate": "./index.html",
      "sensorAppOneLink": "http://onelink.to/pca6qe",
      "sensorPhone": true,
      "contentSecurityPolicy": "base-uri 'none'; default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' http: https: ws: wss:; connect-src 'self' http: https: ws: wss:;  script-src 'self' open.mapquestapi.com *.twitter.com *.twimg.com *.aptrinsic.com 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data:; style-src * 'unsafe-inline' blob:; img-src * data:; font-src * data:; frame-src *; worker-src 'self' blob:;",
      "dynamicOptionsUrl": "/apps/public/public-options/options.json"
    },
    "cli": {}
  }
}
```